# Sql connection error from Xp to Windows 7 via C# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, network-programming

I deployed c# app with Sql DB ,Now I wanted to test it on the local network
server:Windows 7 Pro
Client:Windows Xp sp3 (VMWARE)

In my connection String I just set the server ip address but I get Connection error !!
If there is any setting which must be set plz help me?

when I try to start sql server browser it show following error
[image]

Comment: show your connection string and the error that you get

Comment: connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.5 \ sqlexpress;database=OxygenDB;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: I think the problem is in network connection because when I want to connect to server by win xp it ask me for username and password

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Answer (score 0):

[Enable TCP protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on your SQL Server instance, [allow remote connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx) in Windows Firewall on server and check if your virtual machine (client) has network access to server (ping, telnet).

Comment: when Ping from client it shows reply but when I want to connect to server by Ip from windows(not app) it ask for username and password

Comment: Check the link in my answer.

Comment: tcp protocol was enabled @artplastika

Comment: problem is on windows authentication I guess

Comment: Check your firewall settings on server (see the second link in my answer).